Why aren't some "conditions" officially a condition? (Burning, Bloodied)
D&D 2024 introduces "Burning [hazard]" and "Bloodied", and this lead me to wonder, why aren't these a "condition"? It sounds very much like they are, but they don't seem to be according to the rules as written. Is there something inherently associated with the definition of a condition that doesn't fit or breaks something? Just curious, they seem to fit the definition of "temporary game state" perfectly, and Burning also has an effect (1d4 fire damage). The thing about bloodied is that it doesn't have any "effects", so that may cause it to not be a condition?
(I could think of a few more game definitions that could possibly be regarded as a "condition", but none of these were as clear-cut as the two I mention here).

Turns out it's right there in the book, in the same paragraph. Part of what makes a condition, is that it "[...] alters the recipients capabilities".
"Bloodied" and "Burning" do not alter the recipients capabilities.
